# subprocess in python3 and it's parameters

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

How is subprocess.Popen different from os.fork()? The doc just says it creates a child program in a new process.

And what does this code specifically do?

```
from subprocess import PIPE

subprocess.Popen("ls", shell = True, stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
```

I'm specifically confused about the parameters, stdin = PIPE, stdout and stderr = PIPE), again, the doc says that they are special valuesthat can be used to Popen and indicates a pipe to the standard stream should be opened.

Does this mean that it's setting the default standard stream to stdin, stdout or stderr respectively?

Plus, I didn't get the documentation listing something like:

```
process = Popen(some_command, shell = True, stdin = Pipe....#same code)

process.stdin.write(#some binary data)
```

We're not accessing the arguments here are we?
How is this code all working?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) are pretty good on this topic, what is your specific question?

Comment: @AnthonySottile, I did find out the difference between fork and Popen, but I'm confused with the PIPE process. First we do process.stdin.write(#something), and then I close() the pipe, process.stdin.close() but it gives me a BrokenPipeError, however, that's what is given in the book.

Comment: You probably want to use `proc.communicate(...)` instead (the docs also mention this to avoid broken pipe / deadlocks